# system-installation automatically directed to burning to a disk on E drive

Tags: system-installation

When I download Ubuntu, I am automatically directed to burning to a disk on E drive. Can I use USB? How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Windows. In order to write the file to a USB drive properly, a third-party application is required. Try using [UNetBootIn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net), which will do all the steps automatically. Download the Windows version, then run it. Once it's been opened, select the file you downloaded from the Ubuntu website, and choose the flash drive you wish to install it to. Once it's finished installing, reboot using the flash drive as the boot source. (This may require editing the boot order in the BIOS settings -- make sure the flash drive is plugged in before powering on to enter BIOS settings.) Once the operating system for the Ubuntu installer loads, follow its instructions and read everything carefully before making  any decisions.